# How to configure android map sdk v2 to use different keys for production and development?

Tags: android, google-maps, ant, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to automatically set different android map api V2 keys for development and production.

Comment: Easiest and quickest way http://stackoverflow.com/a/40484330/1348522

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Log in to Google APIs Console
Under "Simple API Access" click "Edit Allowed Android apps..." on the right side
Enter one SHA-1 fingerprint per line like the instructions say:

"One SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name (separated by a semicolon) per line. Example: 
45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example
45:B6:E4:6F:36:AD:1A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F1:56:26:A0:E0;com.example"

Now, just use the same "Simple API key" and it'll work for your debug and publish certificate without having to change anything.

Comment: thanks, i removed all staff related to ant. since ant is not necessary at all to solve this.

Answer (score 7):

I may be wrong, but I think you can use the same V2 API key for both development and production builds. In your Google APIs Console, after generating a simple Android key, you just need to enter the SHA-1 fingerprints of your production signing key, and all the development Android debug signing keys you may have. Then in your manifest, just use that simple Android key and the app should work for both debug and production builds.

Answer (score 3):

One of the easiest solution.You can achieve it with two simple steps.

Add custom value to manifestplaceholders `build.gradle` file.
See below

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapApiKeyValue:"GHjaSyAjlyp3O831lgaonHMXsd-_DpQ3002x3S4"]
    }

    release {
        manifestPlaceholders = [ mapApiKeyValue:"AIzaSyAuMGDLr2HeuRed4JA0CrdYYdZRjeC3EA"]
    }
}
```

Edit manifest file like below.
part of my manifest file

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="${mapApiKeyValue}" />
```

This solution works for the latest Android 5.0 and Android 6.0 (API 20, 21,22,23)

Comment: How does the app know which one to use?

Comment: When you test your app its debug mode. When you create signed apk and run that, its release mode.